# How to convert curl file post from command line into PHP cURL

Tags: php, post, file-upload, curl

I'm trying to post files to a 3rd party API from my PHP app.
This works from the command line:

```
curl -F "file=@move_file.MOV" "https://upload.wistia.com?project_id=pbmcmua3ot&username=api&api_password=xxxxx_apikey_yyyyy"
```

But I can't get it to work using PHP's curl:

```
    $data = array(
        'username'      => $username,
        'api_password'  => $api_password,
        'file'          => fopen($tmp_filename, 'r'),
        'project_id'    => $project_hashed_id,
        );


    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.wistia.com" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); // 1 Day Timeout

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, fopen($tmp_filename, 'r') );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($tmp_filename));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); //for debugging
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result);
```

I think `CURLOPT_INFILE` is the problem but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

**UPDATE1**

```
    $data = array(
        'username'      => $username,
        'api_password'  => $api_password,
        'file'          => '@'.$tmp_filename,
        'project_id'    => $project_hashed_id,
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.wistia.com" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); // 1 Day Timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($tmp_filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); //for debugging
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result);
```

**UPDATE 2 (Working)**

```
    $data = array(
        'api_password'  => $api_password,
        'file'          => '@'.$tmp_filename,
        'project_id'    => $project_id
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.wistia.com" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to open a handle for curl, just have

```
$data = array(
    'file' => '@move_file.MOV'
);
```

Curl will see the `@` and treat it as a file upload attempt. You also don't have to do `http_build_query()` either. Curl can accept an array directly and do the query building itself:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: The docs from the API (http://wistia.com/doc/upload-api#the_request) state: "All parameters (with the exception of file) may be encoded into the request body or included as part of the query string.

The file parameter must be multipart-form encoded into the request body."

Is the "@" syntax compatible with this?

Comment: I think this is also necessary : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`. Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#example-4182) for more info.

Comment: + Although clearly listed in [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), I did not know about `@`. Looks like it's deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: I just added an update which I think contains @redreggae and MarcB's fixes. It still doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: @jason: it's deprecated because it made it impossible for curl to send a non-file parameter that started with a `@` char...

Comment: @Emerson please try the minimal example in the link that I posted.

Comment: @Marc B, good to know. Thanks for the thorough answer. Learned something.

Comment: @redreggae I got it to work with the minimal example straight from the PHP docs (see my update 2). Any ideas why it wasn't working with the additional options? I'm not sure if I need them. All I really need is a way to track the upload progress so I can report back to the user via AJAX.

Comment: @Emerson you should try it with the option `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`

Comment: @redreggae That's exactly what I need! However, I'm not sure how to access the return from the callback. Do you? WARNING (For anyone following along): the parameters passed from CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION changed from 4 to 5 as of PHP 5.5.