# How can I use cURL to post form data in php?

Tags: php, curl

I have the following command, which uses the --form/--F option, which I know to be working:

```
curl  --form "file=@/home/USERNAME/import.csv" https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports\?token\=[KEY]
```

I need to run this command via php, but I'm having trouble, presumably with the form file data. I tried the following, however echoing or var_dumping the result seems to show nothing, just a blank page or a blank string.

```
<?php 
$target_url = 'https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports?token=[KEY]'
$file_name_with_full_path ='/home/USERNAME/import.csv';
$post = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($result);?>
```

How can I get this command working in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert curl file post from command line into PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865817)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

since no answer got it right thus far (at least not with an approach that would work in php 5.6+), here goes: the equivalent php curl_ code would be:

```
$ch = curl_init ( 'https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports?token=[KEY]' );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array (
                'file' => new CURLFile ( '/home/USERNAME/import.csv' ) 
        ) 
) );
curl_exec ( $ch );
```

(i would also recommend setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to emptystring, especially if you expect the response to be compressible, that would be the equivalent of adding `--compressed` to the curl command line, and might speed things up)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
<?php 
$target_url = 'https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports?token=[KEY]'
$file_name_with_full_path ='/home/USERNAME/import.csv';
$post = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

$curlresponse = json_decode($result, true);

var_dump($curlresponse);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `CURLFile` instead of @ for PHP version above 5.5

```
$target_url = 'https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports?token=[KEY]'
$file_name_with_full_path ='/home/USERNAME/import.csv';
// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = new CURLFile($file_name_with_full_path,mime_content_type($file_name_with_full_path),'imported_csv');    
// Assign POST data
$post = array('imported_csv_file' => $cfile);    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: you dont need to enable CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, but yes, always use CURLFile.

Comment: warning, as of PHP 7.0, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD doesn't even exist

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
<?php 
$target_url = 'https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports?token=[KEY]'
$file_name_with_full_path ='/home/USERNAME/import.csv';
$post = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($post)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result = curl_exec($curl)
if(!$result){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This worked for me. You can try it

```
  $authHeader = array('Accept: application/form-data');

  $post_fields =  "client_id=" . $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $client_secret;

  send_curl_request("POST", $authHeader, $url, $post_fields);

function send_curl_request($method, $headers, $url, $post_fields){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  if(count($headers) > 0){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //echo '<br> HEADER ADDED<br><br>';
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
  if($method == "POST"){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    //echo '<br> POST FIELDS ADDED<br><br>';
  } 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib
https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class
and then

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->post('https://www.example.com/login/', array(
    'username' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
));
```

Comment: that definitely will not upload $file_name_with_full_path  - but maybe this would (idk, i dont know that library): `$curl->post('https://www.example.com/login/', array(
    'username' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'file'=>new CURLFile($file_name_with_full_path)
));`

Comment: Hi,
This library is one of best curl lib for php.
Please add library with instruction in this url 
[link]https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/README.md[/link]
this.
and then You can use some examle of this like file uploader.
file uploader example: [link]https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/examples/multi_curl_upload_file.php[/link]

Comment: I don't know that library, and although I might check it out, I have little interest in learning it. But the point is, your example code does _NOT_ do what OP wants to do, you should probably fix that (also I'm the author of [another curl_ wrapper](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php#L477) that does pretty much the same, and it's working fine for me, thus my disinterest)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing link to the library, it is so handy and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You need to read file data and then attach data on post fields.

Try this, this should work. If doesn't work, make sure `fread()` can read your file. Reading can be failed due to many reason.

```
$target_url = 'https://apiprovider.com/api/v0/imports?token=[KEY]'

$file_name_with_full_path ='/home/USERNAME/import.csv';
$fileHandler = fopen($file_name_with_full_path, 'r');
$fileData = fread($fileHandler, filesize($file_name_with_full_path));

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

$headers = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fileHandler);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_name_with_full_path));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fileData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: no, it shouldn't work, and if this works for you, you should upgrade your PHP installation, because your PHP version is EOL. this wont work in PHP 5.6+. use CURLFile instead.

Comment: no it doesnt. here is the request his curl command is making: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7e7057d995c0f310a84e81d71c9368b - and here is the request your php code is making (after fixing the typo on line 9 which makes your code connect to NULL-127.0.0.1 by mistake, you are missing a dollar sign): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85f82e2787d9dd18b0ec44bb159f9a86 - those 2 requests are not even remotely similar.

Comment: - but your code is failing in a different way than i initially thought when first reading through it.